# How to pass ADS (Arguments with dynamic strings) which can have spaces from VBscript to Powershell

Tags: powershell, vbscript, hta

I wanted to know if it is possible to pass arguments to powershell via VBscript.

Here is my code and my investigation on this topic so far.

VBscript:

```
Dim pathvalue (pathvalue will dynamic path, which may have spaces in it. lets say path is "\\Server\search\File in some folder\Stack Overflow\")
sCmd = "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -noexit -File \\server\Support\abhishek\Automation\SearchUtility.ps1 -Inputs " & PathValue
Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
iResult = oShell.Run(sCmd, 1, true)
```

PS1.

```
Param([String] $Inputs)
$FolderPath = $Inputs;
echo "$FolderPath";
```

Expected result :

`\\Server\search\File in some folder\Stack Overflow\`

Actual Result :

`\\Server\search\File`

I tried different methods to pass the arguments ex. by putting it in single quotes, by putting 3 double Quotes but still it is not working.

Here is a code example:

`sCmd = "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -noexit -File \\server\Support\abhishek\Automation\SearchUtility.ps1 -Inputs " &"'" & PathValue & "'"`

I got stuck for days and I haven't found a way to get this done. I need some help here. (I am new to Powershell)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You don't need to build it in steps like this. I just did it this way to make it more readable. The last line is the critical part.

```
sCmd = "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -noexit "
sCmd = sCmd & "-File \\server\Support\abhishek\Automation\SearchUtility.ps1 "
sCmd = sCmd & "-Inputs " & Chr(34) & PathValue & Chr(34)
```